# Getting common flags enum value in c#

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

Say I have the below enum

```
[Flags]
enum Letters
{
     A = 1,
     B = 2,
     C = 4,
     D = 8,
     E = 16,
     F = 32,
     AB = A | B,
     All = A | B | C,
}
```

If I have the variables:

```
var s = Letters.A | Letters.B | Letters.D;
var p = Letters.A | Letters.C | Letters.D | Letters.E;
```

What I want is to get the common values between these two enums so in this case it should be `A | D`. Can some one please tell me how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get that using the binary & (and) operator:

```
var s = Letters.A | Letters.B | Letters.D;
var p = Letters.A | Letters.C | Letters.D | Letters.E;
var sAndp = s & p; // This will give you only the common values ( A & D)
```

Comment: Awesome..Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Just as you use `|` to get a union of values, you can use the `&` to get the intersection:

```
var s = Letters.A | Letters.B | Letters.D;
var p = Letters.A | Letters.C | Letters.D | Letters.E;

var intersection = s & p;  // A | D
var union = s | p;         // All | D | E
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result:

```
    var result =  s & p;
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's suitable for you it will return List of individual flags

```
 static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(Enum input)
    {
        foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(input.GetType()))
            if (input.HasFlag(value))
                yield return value;
    }

GetFlags(s).Intersect(GetFlags(p))
```